# Wordpress Ajax Lite Placement

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have installed the Ajax Search Lite plugin for my wordpress site and have edited the Header.php file to place the code. 
This is the code that I am currently using to display it:

```
<body>
<!-- Header -->
<section>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite'); ?>
```

This is how it displays on my site currently and in the same screenshot points out where I would like place it: 
[Ajax Search Lite Placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5bUN.jpg)

Is anyone able to help me achieve this? Is there a better way to implement the search function where I want rather than in the Header.php file?

Any assistance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

approach # 1 : add the short code, in the menu or theme files where your menu is getting rendered. (or)

approach # 2: You don't need a walker in this case. A filter called wp_nav_menu_items is available. It allows you to edit the list items of a menu. Just append your own list item with search field.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 10, 2 );

function add_search_to_nav( $items, $args )
{
    $items .= '<li>SEARCH'.do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite').'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

Ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52286/using-a-menu-walker-add-a-custom-item-at-the-end-of-the-menus-items

Comment: Thanks, where in the wordpress UI would i implement approach # 2?

Comment: It is a filter and you can call it in your theme’s functions.php file or a site specific plugin.

Comment: I also have Max Mega Menu plugin installed. How would this affect what you are saying as I can't find the right area to add either of your approaches?

Comment: add it in functions.php of your current active theme, it will work and get reflected.

Comment: When I add it to functions.php I get the following error message "add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 10, 2 ); function add_search_to_nav( $items, $args ) { $items .= '
SEARCH'.do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]').'
'; return $items; }
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wwwwha5/public_html/footybootsdb.com/wp-content/themes/bentochildtheme/functions.php:14) in /home/wwwwha5/public_html/footybootsdb.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1195"

Comment: OK I have now got it working - thank you for your assistance!. How do I get it to sit on the same line as the other menu items? And remove the text that says 'Search'? [Search field visible](http://imgur.com/a/5AfNh)

Comment: welcome. You can remove the search text in the functions.php which is added instead of $items .= '<li>SEARCH'.do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite').'</li>'; mention without SEARCH Text. Using CSS you can handle the alignment issues. If you find the answer useful, please vote or accept it as accepted answer.